# Tengo un problema con los métodos al aplicar herencia

Tags: java, herencia

verán cree mi clase padre: Persona (con getset para Nombre y Apellido) luego una clase hija Profesor (agregué CodigoProfesor) y de esta sus hijas ProfesorTiempoCompleto y ProfesorPorHoras

Luego cargue esta clase para colocar lo que me vaya a salir:

public class MetodosFinales {

```
private Persona[] personas;

public MetodosFinales(){
    personas = new Persona[4];
}

public void LlenarAarreglo(){
    personas[0] = new AlumnoPregrado(4,"Ingenieria", 14.5f, 5558888,"Pedro","Moron");
    personas[1] = new AlumnoPostgrado("Ingenieria", 8888555, "Cesar", "Vilchez");
    personas[2] = new ProfesorTiempoCompleto(5020f, 575757, "Casimiro", "Ulloa");
    personas[3] = new ProfesorPorHoras(60f, 40, 757575, "Jorge", "Arevalo");
}

public void MostrarPlantilla(){
    System.out.println("\nInformación de los profesores");
    for(int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
        String LineaProfesores =    personas[i].getNombre() +
                                    personas[i].getApellido() +

    }
}
```

}

Osea cree un arreglo de objetos de la clase Persona, pero quiero adicionar los metodos de CodigoProfesor (que se encuentra en la clase Profesor) pero no me aparecen y si lo escribo me sale error
Creo entender que no me permite colocarlo, porque no es un metodo de la clase persona sino de una de sus clases hijas, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de lograrlo, porque sí o sí debo sacar el arreglo de objetos de la clase Personas, porque sé que si lo hiciese de la clase Profesor, normal podría colocar todos los métodos. Ayuda por favor

Comment: Has probado a castear tu objeto `Persona` a las clases `ProfesorTiempoCompleto` o `ProfesorPorHoras`? `((ProfesorTiempoCompleto) personas[I]).getCodigoProfesor();`

Comment: Podrias explicar eso de castear el objeto por favor; y como solucionaria esta duda que tengo?

Comment: `Castear` se refiere a convertir un objeto de la clase A a la clase B. Deberías echar un vistazo ha este post por ejemplo http://labojava.blogspot.com/2012/05/casteos.html?m=1 es un término con el que te vas a encontrar a menudo.

Comment: Creo entender lo del casteo, mi duda es, ahora donde colocaría: ((ProfesorTiempoCompleto) personas[I]).getCodigoProfesor();
Antes de inicializar el arreglo, despues, o en qué lugar hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

El método debería ser así:

```java
public void MostrarPlantilla(){
    System.out.println("\nInformación de los profesores");    
    for(int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
        String codigo = "";
        if(persona[i] instanceof Profesor) {
             Profesor p = (Profesor) persona[i];
             codigo = p.getCodigoProfesor();
        }

        String LineaProfesores = personas[i].getNombre() + personas[i].getApellido() + codigo } }
```

Por partes, tus profesores, independientemente de que sean `ProfesorTiempoCompleto` o `ProfesorPorHoras` heredan de la clase `Profesor` que tiene el campo código que necesitas.

La palabra reservada `instanceof` sirve para determinar si un objeto puede ser casteado, es decir, convertido, a una clase en concreto. Si el objeto hereda de la clase `Profesor` entonces se puede convertir, lo que te dará acceso a la propiedad código.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres sacar partido de la programación orientada a objetos, lo que deberías hacer (en mi opinión) es delegar la responsabilidad de generar su "línea" a cada objeto. Es decir, añadir un método "generarLínea" a cada objeto, que construye el String a mostrar:

```
public class Persona {
  protected String nombre;
  protected String apellido;

  [...]
  public String generarLinea() {
    return nombre + " " + apellido;
  }
  [...]
}

public class Profesor extends Persona {
  private String codigo;

  [...]
  @Override
  public String generarLinea() {
    return nombre + " " + apellido + " - " + codigo; 
  }
  [...]
}
```

A partir de aquí, tan sólo tienes que invocar al método "generarLinea" de un objeto Persona para que generar el texto adecuado en cada caso:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    //Versión "clasica"
    Persona[] personas = new Persona[4];
    personas[0] = new Persona("Pedro","Moron");
    personas[1] = new Persona("Cesar", "Vilchez");
    personas[2] = new Profesor("Casimiro", "Ulloa","1111");
    personas[3] = new Profesor("Jorge", "Arevalo","2222");

    System.out.println("\n** Clasica ** Información de los profesores");
    for (Persona persona : personas) {
      System.out.println(persona.generarLinea());
    }

    //Versión "moderna"
    ArrayList<Persona> personas2 = new ArrayList<>();
    personas2.add(new Persona("Pedro","Moron"));
    personas2.add(new Persona("Cesar", "Vilchez"));
    personas2.add(new Profesor("Casimiro", "Ulloa","1111"));
    personas2.add(new Profesor("Jorge", "Arevalo","2222"));

    System.out.println("\n** Moderna ** Información de los profesores");
    personas2.forEach(persona -> System.out.println(persona.generarLinea()));

  }
```

Este sería el resultado de la ejecución:

```
** Clasica ** Información de los profesores
Pedro Moron
Cesar Vilchez
Casimiro Ulloa - 1111
Jorge Arevalo - 2222

** Moderna ** Información de los profesores
Pedro Moron
Cesar Vilchez
Casimiro Ulloa - 1111
Jorge Arevalo - 2222
```